# use UIActivityViewController to serve data with different format

Tags: ios, objective-c, email, uiactivityviewcontroller, airdrop

In my app, I would like to share shopping list. Let's say, I would like to share the shopping list in two different ways:

1. Through `AirDrop` with a `schema url`, which will bring up my app on another device, and the receiving app adds the shared items to its shopping list.
2. Through `email`, which sends an `email` with the items on the shopping list as a `HTML document` in a table format.

So bascially there are two different strings to be shared across depend on whether the activity type is `AirDrop` or `email`. The below code does not work, in the sense that it is always the `schema URL` got sent, even for `email`:

```
url = [@"myapp://shoppinglist?apple=12&orange=5" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];    
UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[url] applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:controller animated:NO completion:nil];
```

I dug a bit, but could not find out how to send different contents based on the method of sharing.

My question is how to do what I described here with `UIActivityViewController`? Or whether it is even doable - whether `UIActivityViewController` was meant for this or has the flexibility for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to create and share two objects that conform to the [UIActivityItemSource](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActivityItemSource_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIActivityItemSource), where one returns the HTML and the other one the URL. Then when the delegate callback requesting the item is called you check which activity type was selected (Facebook, Mail, AirDrop, etc) and have one or the other return nil if that item doesn't apply.

So in the case of AirDrop, only the item source for the URL will return a non-nil value. You can take a look at the [airdrop sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/sc2273/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013842) to get some examples of how to implement UIActivityItemSource